# Associate color with number in a scatterplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I'm using sklearn to do a kmeans cluster based on some retail data.

We're using this cluster behind the scenes to segment customers (e.g., Blue customers are great, green customers have such-and-such a need, etc.).

The datapoints shown are a different color based on which of 4 clusters a customer has been put into.  But I can't find a way to directly infer which color is which segment number (or how to force certain segment numbers to be a certain color).

`c=y` in the scatter is where it's using the value of y (i.e., the predicted segment for an observation) to pick the color.  There are 4 segments.  I just don't know which of those 4 gets mapped to which color!

Can someone please advise on how I can add a legend, or force the color myself?

```
kmeans=kmeans.fit(X)
y=kmeans.predict(X)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
ax.view_init(30)
ax.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], X[:, 2], c=y)
ax.set_xlabel(vx)
ax.set_ylabel(vy)
ax.set_zlabel(vz)
```

[image: scatter]

Comment: did you try ax.legend() ?

Comment: ```No handles with labels found to put in legend.``` I guess that gives me something to google in the meantime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return a handle from scatter and plot colorbar,

```
cm = ax.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], X[:, 2], c=y)
plt.colorbar(cm)
```

As a minimal example

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

X = np.random.randn(100,3)
y = np.random.randn(100)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
ax.view_init(30)
cm = ax.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], X[:, 2], c=y)
plt.colorbar(cm)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Ugh, that's what I needed.  I was just doing ax.scatter (not keeping it, like you are with the ```cm=```.  I guess i need to go back and fix my fundamentals.  Thanks!

Comment: @Chris, it's not obvious when colormesh, contourf, etc automatically pick up the colorbar without needing you to pass an explict handle, `cm` here